# Скачать xml файл по URL, используя C#

Tags: c#, xml, url

Подскажите, как скачать по URL xml файл в папку проекта, используя C#?

Comment: Сами что пробовали? Ведь это пару строк кода, которые легко гуглятся. Или хотите, чтоб за вас думали, делали проект, а вы в сторонке сидели?

Answer (score 1):

Или даже с помощью `XDocument`, если это XML.

**c#**

```
const string Url = @"http://hurt.super-toys.pl/xml/super_toys_ceneo_pelny.xml";
const string fileName = @"e:\temp\toys.xml";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Url);
doc.Save(fileName);
```